# How trigger a Livevalidation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

How can I trigger a Live validation on an element that is usually validated on a blur event ? I did not find out how I could change the event that trigger the LiveValidation, client sided.

My problem is that some fields'styles are updated using a Live validation, and this update occur on the blur event.

I tried to trigger a **blur** event on the element, so the style can change even without user interaction.

```
$(element_id).blur();
```

..but it did not work. Can I change the event that make LiveValidation react ?

Comment: use the change event

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to run a function when someone types in a; *textarea, input, etc.*

There is a simple way where you can add the **oninput** attribute.

```
<input type="text" oninput="myFunction()">
```

If you want to know more about **oninput**, visit http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp

Unfortunately, There is **no way** to do this on jQuery, as it has not **implemented** yet.

EDIT:

You are able to do it on jQuery, but there is **no handler**.

```
$("input")[0].oninput();
```

-CowNecromancer